# In tkinter for Python, can someone identify why <<ListBoxSelect>> is not firing?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to develop a small database application using tkinter in python.  I have a small database which has inventory numbers for various assets.  I have successfully constructed the listbox using tkinter and managed to populate it using sqlite3's library.

I've been trying to get the << ListBoxSelect >> event bound to which item is selected in the listbox and to output the asset's information.  Several hours later, all I'm trying to do now is get the bind event to fire at all and print out a simple string until I can figure it out.

Before I post my code, I used [This code snippet](https://codebyexamples.com/python-examples/python-using-the-tkinter-listbox-widget/) to see if I could get ANY binding event to work.  This code snippet does in fact work however trying to integrate the way its written into my own code has not been successful.  The event binder simply does not fire in my code at all.  Can anyone please identify why this is or what I'm doing incorrectly?

Please see relevant code below (please note the indenting is not correct when trying to paste it into this forum):

```
class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):

    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    # Create Widgets

    self.invListbox = tk.Listbox(self, height=20, width=10, selectmode=tk.SINGLE)
    self.assetDescLabel1 = tk.Label(self, text="Asset Description")
    self.assetDescEntry1 = tk.Entry(self)
    self.exitButton = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", command=exit)

    # Configure Widgets
    # Updates assetDescEntry based on invListbox selection

    self.invListbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.invOnSelect())

    # Place Widgets

    self.invListbox.grid(row=1, column=1)
    self.assetDescLabel1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    self.assetDescEntry1.grid(row=2, column=2)
    self.exitButton.grid(row=2, column=1)

    # Populate invListbox
    self.InvList = main.sqlInventoryNumberList()
    for row in self.InvList:
        item = row[0]
        self.invListbox.insert(1, item)


def invOnSelect(self):
    selection = "This is just a regular old string"
    print(selection)
```

Comment: maybe because it is `ListboxSelect` and not `ListBoxSelect`

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken. Plus, there are many other reasons why we can't run your code (missing imports, for example). This is very far from a [mcve], it would help if you reduced it way down. If the problem is with a binding, we problem don't need much more than the one widget, the binding, the bound function, and enough to make that work.

Comment: Thanks!  I've edited based on what you mentioned.  Since the problem is with the binding I removed everything exterior to the class the binding is located.  I included everything else originally (less the function to populate the listbox) so others could cut'n'paste it but the indents didn't seem to stick so I had to try and do it manually.  I've also corrected the typo in the << ListboxSelect >> and while the event fires upon initialization, it doesn't fire when the listbox selection changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get the code above to run as too much is missing.  You must bind a function in the bind statement not the result of a function.  So `.bind( ... , func )` NOT `.bind(..., func() )`.  Your function must take an event object too.  Below is a minimal working example.

```
import tkinter as tk

def invOnSelect(event):
    selection = "This is just a regular old string"
    print( event, selection )           

root = tk.Tk()

invListbox = tk.Listbox( root, height=20, width=10, selectmode=tk.SINGLE )
invListbox.grid()

invListbox.bind( '<<ListboxSelect>>', invOnSelect ) # invOnSelect has no brackets here.

InvList = [ '1', '2', '3' ]
for item in InvList:
    invListbox.insert(tk.END, item)


root.mainloop()
```

The ideas should integrate into your application.

Comment: Thanks Chris!  I was able to get the event to fire properly by changing the syntax a bit.  Specifically, I removed the brackets on invOnSelect in the binder and in the function definition I included the two arguments (self, evt).  Everything works just great now, thank you very much!